# How to get bottom control bar's height in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to get the bottom control bar's height in flutter,
I tried `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom`, but it returned 0.0

[image: this one right here]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the kBottomNavigationBarHeight constant. [View the docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/kBottomNavigationBarHeight-constant.html&ved=2ahUKEwiX1ZmE-PHrAhXAxjgGHaa-DqEQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2DBF4dXk2C1OYQg1h2ny3r)

Comment: I don't think it  is as tall as  BottomNavigationBar, That's the control bar on android device